# Reescribiendo autenticación de laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, autenticación

Estoy reescribiendo la autenticación de laravel 5.6 en mi proyecto; la tabla en la que debe buscar los datos es usuario (no user como lo tiene laravel por defecto) en mi controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        return view('login.index');
    }  

    public function login(Request $request){

        $user = Usuario::where('usr_usuario', $request->usr_usuario)->get()->first();
        //dd($user);
        if (!empty($user)) {
            if (Hash::check($request->pas_usuario, $user['PAS_USUARIO']))
            {
                // Realizar operaciones si la contraseña es la misma.
                //echo "realiza la comparación y es verdadera";
                //return "éxito";

                return redirect()->route('bienvenida');
            }
            else {
                return back()->withErrors(['usr_usuario' => "Los datos no corresponden a ningún registro"]);
            }

        } else {
            return back()->withErrors(['usr_usuario' => "Los datos no corresponden a ningún registro"]);
        }
    }  
}
```

En mi archivo de rutas::

```
//Autenticación
Route::get('/entrar', 'LoginController@index')->name('ingresar');
Route::post('/entrar/login', 'LoginController@login');

//Luego de autenticarse exitosamente
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('bienvenida');
```

Y la vista a la que quiero redireccionar una vez autenticado:::

```
@extends ('admin.layout')
@section('title', 'AdminLTE')
@section('content_header')
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
@stop
@section('content')
    <p>Estás logueado</p>
    <h1>{{ dd(auth()->user()) }}</h1>
@stop
```

Ahora bien, todo esto funciona, busca el usuario, compara las contraseñas, etc...
El problema es que no sé cómo recuperar las "variables de sesión" o cómo sobreescribir las variables auth de laravel para que me traiga la info de la tabla usuarios... ésta línea `{{ dd(auth()->user()) }}`  es para probar y viene con un montón de información pero nada es el nombre de usuario que debería traer de `usuario.usr_nombre`

¿Alguien sabe cómo se hace ésto?

---

Hasta el momento sin éxito, seguiré intentando y cuando consiga la solución lo publicaré.  Me niego a aceptar que sea imposible customizar del todo éste dichoso framework...

Comment: laravel usa Sentinel: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#authentication para realizar las autenticaciones, Creo que su problema es que desconecto el Auth de Sentinel. Ahora debería pensárselo bien antes de modificar esto, como recomendación le sugiero que cree tablas alternas.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. No entiendo a qué se refiere con "le sugiero que cree tablas alternas" la tabla alterna está creada, es usuario.

Comment: Usted esta reemplazando la tabla users que utiliza sentinel con la nueva tabla que creo. Con tablas alternas me refiero a que si necesita agregar más campos para users, cree una tabla nueva y la relaciona con usuarios, por ejemplo una tabla users_contacts: y esta la relaciona a través de user_id a la tabla users.

Comment: Gracias por su explicación

Answer (score 1):

El framework por si solo no puede descubrir que se ha modificado el modelo a auntenticar. Por lo que tienes que especificarle a Laravel que estás usando un modelo diferente del *default* (`User`) para la autenticación.

Para hacer esto, dirigete a la configuración de la autenticación (`config/auth.php`), específicamente al apartado `providers`:

**config/auth.php**

```php
// ...
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class, // <---
    ],
],
// ...
```

y reemplaza el valor de `model` por el modelo que estás utilizando:

```php
// ...
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Usuario::class,  // <---
    ],
],
// ...
```

Luego de hacer esto, no olvides limpiar la cache de configuración:

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, ya había modificado el model en el auth pero aún así no me lo toma... Hice el módulo de registro de usuarios con la estructura de mi tabla, pero al hacer el logueo el Auth::Usuario() (sustituyendo el que trae por defecto alravel Auth::user()) no me devuelve nada... Es más, hice debug ---> dd(Auth::attempt($credentials))  y siempre devuelve false

Comment: Luego de modificar la configuración hiciste `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: no, recién lo leí en una respuesta a otra consulta, voy a ejecutarlo. Mil gracias!

Comment: Hasta el momento sin éxito, seguiré intentando y cuando consiga la solución lo publicaré.  Me niego a aceptar que sea imposible customizar del todo éste dichoso framework...

Comment: Gracias @jorge-bowen intentaré a ver si así me funciona